# I tried to implement transparency but something went wrong

Tags: java, alpha-transparency

I wanted to add "transparency" to my Game Engine, which I have no earlier knowledge of. I didn't find any straight answer on how to implement it so I ended up doing some research about something called **Alpha Blending** which is **one** way of showing opacity if I have understood it right.

I Googled around and tried to find a source that showed how to implement this when you have a pixel array. I have no clue how but I found nothing except a tutorial on Youtube. They didn't explain **why** they did like they did and due to that I still have no clue how I can implement it or how it works. I tried to follow the tutorial but the code they used didn't work at all so I changed it a bit (which clearly didn't work).

This code below is my *setPixel()* function that sets a pixel at a specified location. From the start of the function it just checks if it needs to place a pixel at all. This function is used to draw every individual pixel from the pixel data. The pixel data of the screen is stored in the variable **pixels**. The image data is stored in **value**. Value is however just an integer, while pixels is an array..

```
    public void setPixel(int x, int y, int value, Color invis) {
    
    int alpha = (value>>24);
    
    if(invis != null && value == invis.getRGB() || alpha == 0x00) {
        
        return;
    }
    
    if(!isOutSideScreen(x,y)) {
        
        
        
        if(alpha == 255) {
            pixels[x + y * pWidth] = value;
        }
        else {
            int pixelColor =  value;
             
            
            int newRed = ((pixelColor >> 16) & 0xff) + (int)((((pixelColor >> 16) & 0xff) - ((pixels[x + y * pWidth] >> 16) & 0xff)) * (alpha/255f));
            int newGreen = ((pixelColor >> 8) & 0xff) + (int)((((pixelColor >> 8) & 0xff) - ((pixels[x + y * pWidth] >> 8) & 0xff)) * (alpha/255f));
            int newBlue = (pixelColor & 0xff) + (int)(((pixelColor & 0xff) - (pixels[x + y * pWidth] & 0xff)) * (alpha/255f));
            
            
            
            pixels[x+y * pWidth] = ((255 << 24) | (newRed << 16) | (newGreen << 8) | newBlue);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

What I dont understand about this code is all the bitwise code and why you calculate the colors like that.

```
                int newRed = ((pixelColor >> 16) & 0xff) + (int)((((pixelColor >> 16) & 0xff) - ((pixels[x + y * pWidth] >> 16) & 0xff)) * (alpha/255f));
            int newGreen = ((pixelColor >> 8) & 0xff) + (int)((((pixelColor >> 8) & 0xff) - ((pixels[x + y * pWidth] >> 8) & 0xff)) * (alpha/255f));
            int newBlue = (pixelColor & 0xff) + (int)(((pixelColor & 0xff) - (pixels[x + y * pWidth] & 0xff)) * (alpha/255f));
            
            
            
            pixels[x+y * pWidth] = ((255 << 24) | (newRed << 16) | (newGreen << 8) | newBlue);
```

The code acts like this:
[image: GIF]

If someone can explain why this code doesn't work and how  is actually works I would be forever grateful!

Thanks in advance and sorry for my ignorance!

**Edit after Joni's answer**

This is the code I now use:

```
            int pixelColor =  pixels[x+y * pWidth];
             
            
            int newRed  = (int)((1 - (alpha / 255f)) * ((pixelColor>>16) & 0xff) + (alpha / 255f) * ((value >> 16) & 0xff));
            int newGreen  = (int)((1 - (alpha / 255f)) * ((pixelColor>>8) & 0xff) + (alpha / 255f) * ((value >> 8) & 0xff));
            int newBlue  = (int)((1 - (alpha / 255f)) * (pixelColor & 0xff) + (alpha / 255f) * (value & 0xff));
            
            pixels[x+y * pWidth] = ((255 << 24) | (newRed << 16) | (newGreen << 8) | newBlue);
```

I used the formula: `outColor = (1 - alpha) * backgroundColor + alpha * newColor`

Comment: Maybe: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0918/ will help. It shows how to blend two images and you can use transparency on each image.

Comment: @camickr that uses Graphics2D. I use pixel data so I can't use the AlphaComposite class :/. Not what I know of atleast!

Comment: Not really sure what that means. An Array of pixel data is just an array. You can't display an Array of pixels on the screen. You need to do some kind of conversion to an image. You should be able to create a BufferedImage from pixel data. It has a setPixel() method. *The pixel data of the screen is stored in the variable pixels.* - again don't really understand why you are doing. People usually create a BufferedImage of the screen and manipulate the BufferedImage. In your last question you were asked to post an [mre]. You didn't and you didn't here either, so I'm out of guesses.

Comment: @camickr I would love to make an MRE, however this is a game engine and it would result in a huge amount of code. I will try to explain further. I have a frame with a canvas that uses a BufferedStrategy. I use the graphics from the BufferedStrategy to draw a BufferedImage to the screen. This BufferedImage is of type BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB (I also have a pixel array of this image) . I later added my own "drawImage" function where I take the pixel data from an image and then place them on that background image. That is how I use the pixel data :) Now I want to add transparency to the images

Comment: *I have a frame with a canvas that uses a BufferedStrategy. I use the graphics from the BufferedStrategy to draw a BufferedImage to the screen.*  It's much simpler to create a drawing panel by extending a JPanel and overriding the paintComponent method.  Here's Oracle's tutorial: [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: Its not recommended to make a game engine using JPanel as you don’t have a lot of flexibility

Comment: *it would result in a huge amount of code.* - no it doesn't.  We don't care about you application. only the code that demonstrate the problem. That is the whole point of the [mre], to simplify the problem to make sure you understand the problem you are asking about. I provided an "MRE' in my answer below. It is not hard to create if you truly understand your problem. Also a BufferedImage has a setPixel() method. So there is no need to get the pixel data and manipulate it when you can do it directly with the BufferedImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for [alpha blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending) "newColor" on top of "backgroundColor" is:

```
outColor = (1 - alpha) * backgroundColor + alpha * newColor
```

To see why it works, try different values of alpha. With alpha=0, you get background color. With alpha=1, you get newColor.

The formula you've programmed is

```
outColor = backgroundColor + alpha * (backgroundColor - newColor)
```

Alpha = 1 gives you `outColor = 2*backgroundColor-newColor` which is incorrect. To fix it you need to swap `pixelColor` and `pixels[x+y*pWidth]` around - for example for blue channel:

```
int newBlue = (pixelColor & 0xff) + (int)(((pixels[x + y * pWidth] & 0xff) - (pixelColor & 0xff)) * (alpha/255f));
```

> What I dont understand about this code is all the bitwise code and why you calculate the colors like that.

This code assumes a color model that packs four 8-bit integers into one `int`. The most significant 8 bits make up the alpha component, followed by 8bits for the red color component, green color, and blue color each. The way you extract  a component out of an `int` is with bit-wise operators. For example, `color&0xff` is the lowest 8 bits, therefore it's the blue component. `(color>>8)&0xff` gives you the second lowest 8 bits, which is the green component.

Comment: Okay so I got a little bit of a better grip on it now I guess, thanks for the information. I changed the formula to the first one in your answer. It didn't work as expected though. Now I can't see the images at all. I wil update my post with the code that I now use.

Comment: Actually I can see the imagr but it's really transparent. The JPG image of Obama is however gone? I changed the opacity of the "log" image in GIMP to 75% and it turned red.

Comment: you seem to have left out `&0xFF` when extracting the alpha: `int alpha = (value>>24)&0xFF;` the `>>` operator is a sign-extending shift, if value < 0 (meaning alpha>127) the result will be negative. Alternatively use `>>>` instead of `>>`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Do you know where I can read further about bitwise operations and how to extract for example alpha out of an integer? I really want to understand it!

Answer (score 0):

> The pixel data of the screen is stored in the variable pixels.

Don't know if this helps or not but you can create a BufferedImage from an Array of pixels using something like the following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageFromArray3 extends JFrame
{
    int width = 50;
    int height = 50;
    int imageSize = width * height;

    public ImageFromArray3()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( panel );
        int[] pixels = new int[imageSize];

        //  Create Red Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
        {
            //pixels[i] = 255 << 16; // no alpha
            pixels[i] = (64 << 24 ) + (255 << 16);
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Green Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
        {
            //pixels[i] = 255 << 8;
            pixels[i] = (128 << 24 ) + (255 << 8);
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Blue Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
        {
            //pixels[i] = 255;
            pixels[i] = (192 << 24 ) + (255);
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

        //  Create Cyan Image

        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
        {
            //pixels[i] = (255 << 8) + 255;
            pixels[i] = (255 << 24 ) + (255 << 8) + (255);
        }

        panel.add( createImageLabel(pixels) );

    }

    private JLabel createImageLabel(int[] pixels)
    {
        //BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RRGB);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
        raster.setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
        JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(image) );
        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new ImageFromArray3();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

It uses different alpha values for each color.

Now you have your BufferedImage so you should be able to use the AlphaComposite.

Comment: The pixel array is from a BufferedImage actually! I read an image then I took the pixeldata from the image and stores it in pixels. However the pixels array is just the background (there is a bufferedImage as background) and value is the data from the image. I should have mentioned that. I need to use pixel due to me making a game engine. For simple game I would have used Graphics2D

Comment: *The pixel array is from a BufferedImage actually!* - that was the point of my original answer. It showed how to composite two images. You seems to have an image, get the pixels, recreate the image, which seems like a lot of extra work. I was showing you how to do it without the pixels.

Comment: I honestly don’t know. I have just been reading that using Canvas gives you more flexibility with game engines and thays why I went with this solution

Comment: You stated above you use the BufferStrategy to draw the BufferedImage? This is why we need the MRE because you have trouble describing what you are doing.

Comment: The problem is solved. Yes I use a BufferStrategy on a Canvas. I use the graphics (from the BufferStrategy) to draw a BufferedImage. That BufferedImage is of type ARGB. I then save the pixeldata to an array. I now use this BufferedImage as my ”screen pixels”. For example: when I draw an image I replace the pixels from the background BufferedImage at a specific spot with the image pixels. I also clear the ”screen pixels” every 1/60 of a second. This is the basics of What I am doing. No JPanel and I am not using any premade graphics by Graphics2D. I draw all my Circles, images etc on my own.

Comment: @DubstepZedd *I am not using any premade graphics by Graphics2D* - one of us is totally confused. As far as I know even when you use a BufferStrategy you need to invoke the `getDrawGraphics()` method to get a Graphics object. Once you have access to the Graphics object you can then invoke `drawImage(...)` or `fillOval(...)` or `fillRect(...)` on the Graphics object to do your custom painting. So once you have a BufferedImage you can composite two images as described in the original link I provided. Then you draw the composited image.

Comment: The fact that the demo link uses a JPanel to paint the BufferedImage is irrelevant. The point of the article is that you can create a BufferedImage using the AlphaComposite.
Once you have the BufferedImage you can paint it anywhere that you have a Graphics object. I don't know which approach is easier, but I have not seen people do pixel manipulation before when there are classes/methods in the JDK that can do it for you.

Comment: FWIW - here is a link to the tutorial/example I reference when using a BufferStrategy: http://jamesgames.org/resources/double_buffer/double_buffering_and_active_rendering.html

Comment: Yeah I realized that I actually use one Graphics2D function as well. I’ll check it out. I am just not familiar with other ways of doing this that using pixel arrays. Sorry for my ignorance